# Writing variable-length sequence to a compound array

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I am using compound datatypes with h5py, with some elements being variable-length arrays. I can't find a way to set the item. The following MWE shows 6 various ways to do that (sequential indexing — which would not work in h5py anyway, fused indexing, read-modify-commit for columns/rows), neither of which works.

What is the correct way? Why is h5py saying `Cannot change data-type for object array` when writing integer list to `int32` list?

```py
with h5py.File('/tmp/test-vla.h5','w') as h5:
    dt=np.dtype([('a',h5py.vlen_dtype(np.dtype('int32')))])
    dset=h5.create_dataset('test',(5,),dtype=dt)
    dset['a'][2]=[1,2,3] # does not write the value back
    dset[2]['a']=[1,2,3] # does not write the value back
    dset['a',2]=[1,2,3]  # Cannot change data-type for object array
    dset[2,'a']=[1,2,3]  # Cannot change data-type for object array
    tmp=dset['a']; tmp[2]=[1,2,3]; dset['a']=tmp # Cannot change data-type for object array
    tmp=dset[2]; tmp['a']=[1,2,3]; dset[2]=tmp # 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with compound datasets, I've discovered it's best to add all row data in a single statement. I tweaked your code and to show how add 3 rows of data (each of different length). Note how I: 1)  define the row of data with a tuple; 2) define the list of integers with `np.array()`; and 3) don't reference the field name `['a']`.

```
with h5py.File('test-vla.h5','w') as h5:
    dt=np.dtype([('a',h5py.vlen_dtype(np.dtype('int32')))])
    dset=h5.create_dataset('test',(5,),dtype=dt)
    print (dset.dtype, dset.shape)
    dset[0] = ( np.array([0,1,2]), )
    dset[1] = ( np.array([1,2,3,4]), )
    dset[2] = ( np.array([0,1,2,3,4]), )
```

For more info, take a look at this post on the HDF Group Forum under **HDF5 Ancillary Tools** / **h5py**:
[Compound datatype with int, float and array of floats](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/compound-datatype-with-int-float-and-array-of-floats/8083)

Comment: @eudoxos, you haven't commented on this answer. Are you still working in this, or did my answer your problem?

Comment: Sorry for being late. It was a helpful response (though I am not happy about having to working around that, instead of h5py being smart). What I did was based on your idea: read the entire row: `rowdata=dataset[row]`, use dtype names to *find index based on the key*: `rowdata[dataset.dtype.names.index('a')]=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, write back: `dataset[row]=rowdata`.

Comment: I found this issue being tracked in h5py: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/581 .