# h5py: assigning or broadcasting to 2×2 column in a structured array

Tags: python, h5py, array-broadcasting, structured-array

I have record array with 2×2 fixed-size item, with 10 rows; thus the column is 10×2x2. I would like to assign a constant to the whole column. Numpy array will broadcast scalar value correctly, but this does not work in h5py.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
dt=np.dtype([('a',('f4',(2,2)))])
# h5py array
h5a=h5py.File('/tmp/t1.h5','w')['/'].require_dataset('test',dtype=dt,shape=(10,))
# numpy for comparison
npa=np.zeros((10,),dtype=dt)


h5a['a']=np.nan 
# ValueError: changing the dtype of a 0d array is only supported if the itemsize is unchanged

npa['a']=np.nan 
# numpy: broadcasts, OK
```

In fact, I can't find a way to assign the column without broadcasting:

```
h5a['a']=np.full((10,2,2),np.nan)
# ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array
```

Not even one element row:

```
h5a['a',0]=np.full((2,2),np.nan)
# ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you cooy the changed array to the file?

Comment: @hpaulj Not sure what you mean, could you write it in code? But... probably not in this case. Is there no way to assign a single rank-2 field in compound data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [69]: d = f.create_dataset('test', dtype=dt, shape=(3,))
```

We can set a like sized array:

```
In [90]: x=np.ones(3,dt)
In [91]: x[:]=2
In [92]: x
Out[92]: 
array([([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]],), ([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]],),
       ([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]],)], dtype=[('a', '<f4', (2, 2))])
```

and assign it to the dataset:

```
In [93]: d[:]=x
In [94]: d
Out[94]: <HDF5 dataset "test": shape (3,), type "|V16">
In [95]: d[:]
Out[95]: 
array([([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]],), ([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]],),
       ([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]],)], dtype=[('a', '<f4', (2, 2))])
```

We can also  make a single element array with the correct dtype, and assign that:

```
In [116]: x=np.array((np.arange(4).reshape(2,2),),dt)
In [117]: x
Out[117]: array(([[0., 1.], [2., 3.]],), dtype=[('a', '<f4', (2, 2))])
In [118]: d[0]=x
```

With `h5py` we can index with record and field as:

```
In [119]: d[0,'a']
Out[119]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [2., 3.]], dtype=float32)
```

Where as `ndarray` requires a double index as with: `d[0]['a']`

`h5py` tries to imitate `ndarray` indexing, but is not exactly the same.  We just have to accept that.

### edit

The [118] assignment can also be

```
In [207]: d[1,'a']=x
```

The `dt` here just as one field, but I think this should work with multiple fields.  The key is that the value has to be a structured array that matches the `d` field specification.

I just noticed in the docs that they are trying to move away from the `d[1,'a']` indexing, instead using `d[1]['a']`.  But for assignment that doesn't seem to work - not error, just no action.  I think `d[1]` or `d['a']` is a copy, the equivalent of a advanced indexing for arrays.  For a structured arrays those are `view`.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. What is missing for me is how to assign `d[0,'a']` (or `d['a',0]`) — when even self-assignment `h5a['a',0]=h5a['a',0]` fails.

Comment: If `d[0,'a']` assignment is not possible, I will have to work around it like for vlen-fields in compound (which also cannot be assigned): read the whole row (record), write the field, write the whole row back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192725/writing-variable-length-sequence-to-a-compound-array

Comment: This may be as much a limitation of HDF5 as h5py.

Comment: Well, h5py should at least throw an exception which is more descriptive. I will file that at github.

Comment: This issue is already being tracked in h5py (since 2015): https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/645 .

Comment: `d[0,'a']` assignment works - if the `x` has the proper dtype.  See my edits.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. You say that it "works" in the comment though the edit only speculates about that it should work. I would be happy to see a working example. I was not able to create a working one; even `d[1,'a']=d[1,'a']` fails.